# Python discrete fourier transformation

Tags: python, fft

I write my own version of 2d DFT with NumPy, however, it is extremely slow and gives a different result from np.fft.fft2. Is the np fft.fft2 basing on the fast Fourier transformation? Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
def gray_DFT(spatial_img, centerlize = False):
    M,N = spatial_img.shape
    frequency_img = np.zeros(spatial_img.shape)
    for u in range(0,M):
        for v in range(0,N):
            print(u,v)
            mesh_x, mesh_y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(M),np.arange(N), indexing = 'ij')
            matrix = u * mesh_x / M + v * mesh_y / N
            complex_matrix = -2j*np.pi*matrix
            exp_matrix = np.exp(complex_matrix)
            if centerlize:
                transform_matrix = np.power((-np.ones((M,N))), mesh_x + mesh_y)
                frequency_img[u,v] = np.sum(spatial_img*transform_matrix*exp_matrix)
            else:    
                frequency_img[u,v] = np.sum(spatial_img*exp_matrix)
    return frequency_img
```

Comment: “gives a different result from np.fft.fft2” Then yes, there’s something wrong with your code. Please show the results differ, it will help pin-point possible issues with your code.

Comment: Regarding speed, `fft2` indeed uses the Fast Fourier Transform. That is where the name `fft` comes from. But also loops are slow in Python, and you’re not using the separability of the DFT. Separable means you can compute 1D DFT for each row, and then on that resulting matrix, compute 1D DFT on each column (or the other way around, doesn’t matter). This will save a lot of computation.

Comment: I figured out the problem, the frequency_img should be defined with dtype = complex. Thank you for you help on fft2.